# Kendo UI Tree View failed to load child items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have created a Tree View using AngularJS and Kendo UI, also it includes both view and edit toggle for same tree. Now I have problem with my parent as it doesn't have and child sometimes not all time only in edit mode, whole item object turns empty.

**HTML**

```
<div kendo-tree-view="tree" k-data-source="treeData" class="hasMenu" k-on-change="selectedItem = dataItem" id="categoryTree" k-data-bound="onDataBound">
<div k-template ng-class="{disabled: !dataItem.isCatActive}">
    <ul class="multiple_columns">
        <li ng-show="!dataItem.editorEnabled" ng-class="{width30: !dataItem.allowEdit, width160: !dataItem.allowAdd}">
            <span ng-if="dataItem.allowEdit" ng-click="editNode(dataItem, 'cat-'+dataItem.id+dataItem.temp_id)">
                {{dataItem.text}}
            </span>

            <span ng-if="!dataItem.allowEdit">
                {{dataItem.text}}
            </span>
        </li>
        <li ng-if="dataItem.editorEnabled">
            <input ng-model="dataItem.editableData" id="cat-{{dataItem.id + dataItem.temp_id}}" class="form-control width160" ng-blur='updateNode(dataItem)'>
        </li>
        <li class="width40">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-if="dataItem.isCatActive && !dataItem.isParent" ng-click="onInactive(dataItem)" >
            <input type="checkbox" ng-if="!dataItem.isCatActive && !dataItem.isParent" ng-click="changeToActive(dataItem)" checked>
        </li>
        <li ng-if="dataItem.allowTextbox">
            <input type="text" id="salesTaxCode" name="tax_code" ng-model="dataItem.saleTaxCode" class="form-control frm_controllead1 ng-touched" maxlength="13" ng-blur='updateTaxCode(dataItem)'>
        </li>
        <li ng-if="dataItem.allowAdd">
            <button type="button" class="plus_but middle_pbut tooltip-bottom" ng-click="addNew(dataItem)">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o vendor_icon"></i>
            </button>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.treeData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: finalProductArray
});
```